# Stylelint error in Nuxt (class based): Unexpected empty source (no-empty-source)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, stylelint

I get this Stylelint error suddenly in two of my components, I don't know why.

```
Unexpected empty source (no-empty-source)
```

I created a third component and removed content to the point where there is no content left, and the error still shows for that component too.
So what can the issue be?
I tried to understand [this](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/no-empty-source/) eslint documentation page , but I don't understand much of it, it does not explain what a "source" is.

Here is the simplified component (which is not used in the project):

```html
<template>
  <p>ok</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class NewComponent extends Vue {}
</script>

<style lang="postcss" scoped></style>
```

I get:

```
components/common/NewComponent.vue
 12:31  ×  Unexpected empty source   no-empty-source
```

Comment: Line 12 column 31. Might be the empty block. Also is the error Stylelint or ESlint?

Comment: @kissu yes you're right it is a "StylelintError" (i updated the text)

Comment: Do you have some CSS so?

Comment: @kissuu Yes, sorry for late reply. It was the empty CSS block!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was happening because there was an empty `style` tag, removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: It works for SonarQube, too. Thanks!